# running cassandra on a mesos cluster

Tags: cassandra, mesos

I'm trying to deploy Cassandra on a small (test) Mesos cluster. I have one master node (say 10.10.10.1) and three worker nodes: 10.10.10.2-4.

On the official site of apache mesos there is a link to cassandra framework developed for mesos (it is here: https://github.com/mesosphere/cassandra-mesos).

I'm following the tutorial that they provide there. In step 3 they are saying I should edit the conf/mesos.yaml file, specifically that I should set mesos.master.url so that it points to the master node (on which I also have the conf file).

The first thing I tried was just to replace localhost by the master node ip, so I had

```
mesos.master.url: 'zk://10.10.10.1:2181/mesos'
```

but when I then started the deployment script (by running bin/cassandra-mesos as they say in point 5 I should) I get the following error:

```
2015-02-24 09:18:24,262:12041(0x7fad617fa700):ZOO_ERROR@handle_socket_error_msg@1697: Socket [10.10.10.1:2181] zk retcode=-4, errno=111(Connection refused): server refused to accept the client
```

It keeps retrying and displays the same error until I terminate it.

I tried removing 'zk' or replacing it with 'mesos' in the URL, changing (or removing altogether) the port removing the 'mesos' word in the URL but I keep getting the same error.

I also tried looking at how other frameworks do it (specifically spark, which I am hoping to deploy next) but didn't find anything helpful. Any ideas how to run it? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The URL provided to `mesos.master.url` is passed directly to the underlying Mesos Native Java Library. The format listed in your example looks correct.

Next steps in debugging the connection issue would be to verify the IP address the ZooKeeper sever has bound to. You can find out by running `sudo netstat -ntplv | grep 2181` on the server that is running ZooKeeper.

I would expect to see something like the following:

`tcp     0    0    0.0.0.0:2181     0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN   3957/java`

Another possibility could be that ZooKeeper is binding specifically to localhost:

`tcp     0    0    127.0.0.1:2181     0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN   3957/java`

If ZooKeeper has bound to localhost a client will only be able to connect to it with the URL `zk://127.0.0.1:2181/mesos`

#### A note about the future of the Cassandra Mesos Framework.

I am one of the developers working on rewriting the cassandra-mesos project to be more robust, stable and easier to run.  The code in current master(`6aa82acfac`) is end-of-life and will be replaced within the next couple of weeks with the code that is in the [rewrite](https://github.com/mesosphere/cassandra-mesos/tree/rewrite) branch.

If you would like to try out the latest build of the rewrite branch a marathon.json for running the framework can be found [here](https://teamcity.mesosphere.io/guestAuth/repository/download/Oss_Mesos_Cassandra_CassandraFramework/.lastFinished/marathon.json). After downloading the marathon.json update the values for `MESOS_ZK` and `CASSANDRA_ZK` (and any resource values you want to update) then POST the json to marathon at `/v2/apps`.

Comment: Hey Ben, thanks for your explanation. The things is we are not intending to run the zoo keeper at all. It is an analytics cluster and high availability is not really key. With the limited resources we have we can't really afford two more machines. Let me check out the connections and report here later on

Comment: All right, so I realized there is no way I can do the test you are suggesting because I am not running a zookeeper server. I'm looking through documentation but there doesn't seem to be an option of running your framework when ZK is not used... or am I mistaken? If there is then how do I do it?

Comment: Hi marcin_j the connection to ZooKeeper is how the mesos framework locates the elected master.  If the number of machines is an issue for your cluster you can run ZooKeeper on the same servers that the Mesos Masters are running on.  You are correct in that the framework assumes that ZooKeeper is available and can be used for framework persistence.

Answer (score 0):

If you have one master and no zk, how about setting the mesos.master.url to `10.10.10.1:5050` (where 5050 is the default mesos-master port)?

If Ben is right and the Cassandra framework otherwise requires ZK for its own persistence/HA, then try disabling that feature if possible. Otherwise you may have to rip the ZK code out yourself and recompile, if you really want a ZK-free setup (consequently without any HA features).